# Each loop not working as expected

Tags: ruby, loops

I have an array called `@results` that is made up only of arrays. I want to iterate through `@results` and permanently delete any of the inner arrays that are smaller than a given size:

My code:

```
  def check_results limit
    @results.each_with_index do |result, index|
      @results.delete_at(index) if result.size < limit
    end
  end
```

Unfortunately, this only deletes the first item where the array length is less than `limit`. For example if `limit = 4` and `@results = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]` then `check_results` returns `[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]`

I can't figure out why this is happening. Am I using the wrong loop?

Comment: Hello. I edited my answer to include _why_ you are experiencing the issue. I included debug statements. Please take a look at it. I also provide alternatives/solutions to your issue :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do this, as `delete_at` modifies the array, and you will get unexpected behavior if you are deleting elements while iterating it

```
@results.reject { |i| i.size < limit }
```

Above code will exclude all array elements whose size is smaller than `limit`

Comment: I never even thought of `reject`! I like it's use her so I'll accept your answer as soon as SO lets me! Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

It's not a good idea to modify the `@results` array in place as that will conflict with the outer iteration.

What you should do instead is use select to build a new array.

```
def check_results(limit)
  @result.select { |result| result.size > limit }
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `result.size >= limit` based on OP's description of problem?

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly. I just used `==` instead of `>` :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation, [`#delete_at`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at) returns the element at that index.

```
a = ["ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"]
a.delete_at(2)    #=> "cat"
a                 #=> ["ant", "bat", "dog"]
a.delete_at(99)   #=> nil
```

I added some debug statements to show you what is happening at each step, assuming limit is 4:

```
@results = [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
@results.each_with_index do |r, i|
  puts "RESULT: #{r.to_s}"
  puts "INDEX: #{i}"
  @results.delete_at(i) if r.size < 4
  puts "ARRAY: #{@results.to_s}"
end

RESULT: [1, 1, 1, 1]
INDEX: 0
ARRAY: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
RESULT: [1, 1, 1, 1]
INDEX: 1
ARRAY: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
RESULT: [1, 1, 1]
INDEX: 2
ARRAY: [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
# @results == [[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1]]
```

As you can see, the element originally at index 2 has been removed. Because you are modifying `@results` while you are iterating through it, an index of 3 no longer exists, *and* an index of 2 has already been analyzed. This is why you should not modify an object while iterating through it.

Ideally, you want to use [`#delete_if`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if). Similar to methods ending in `!`, `#delete_if` will modify the array (not return a copy of the result), based on conditions from a block (as an argument). The following would be how you would implement the method:

```
def check_results(limit)
  @results.delete_if { |arr| arr.length < limit }
end

@results = [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['bizz', 'bazz'], ['kaboom'] ]

check_results(2)
# => @results == [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['bizz', 'bazz'] ]
```

If you do not want to modify `@results`, then I suggest a similar method, [`#reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Array.html#method-i-reject). Again, `@results` will not be modified, and instead a copy of the results will be returned.

```
def check_results(limit)
  @results.reject { |arr| arr.length < limit }
end

@results = [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['bizz', 'bazz'], ['kaboom'] ]

check_results(2)
# => [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['bizz', 'bazz'] ]
# => @results == [ ['foo', 'bar'], ['bizz', 'bazz'], ['kaboom'] ]
```